# Json deserializing Tuples with named variables

Tags: c#, json, json.net, tuples

I have the following property in a DTO:

```
public IReadOnlyList<(int MyNameA, int MyNameB)> Occurences { get; set; }
```

If I send the following json payload to my MVC controller it woks:

```
"Occurences":[{"Item1" : 10, "Item2" : 2}]
```

however if I send the following then the controller sees `(0,0)` rather than `(10,2)`:

```
"Occurences":[{"MyNameA" : 10, "MyNameB" : 2}]
```

Comment: Just to be sure. Why are you  using a tuple instead of a DateTime format?

Comment: What are you using to deserialize it? Have you checked that the latest version supports the named tuples?

Comment: @aloisdg tks but this is irrelevant to the question that I will edit to give other named variables than Year and Month

Comment: @François ok. I am glad to ask before saying anything more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newtonsoft.Json does not yet have support for C#7 tuples, you can track progress via this GitHub issue: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1230.

I suggest you continute to pass it in as the first example, if you really need it to be named as MyNameA and MyNameB then you could just create a new tuple from the old one.